# Why Pycharm print less than writing to a file?

Tags: python, pycharm

I am testing the following code, I found that the output after the "print" is inconsistent with the text file. I have set the encoding to be "UTF-8". Is this a bug? How to fix?

```
import requests

url = "http://www.aastocks.com/tc/stocks/analysis/company-fundamental/financial-ratios?symbol=0001&period=4"
r = requests.get(url)
print r.content
f = open("test.txt","w")
f.write(r.content)
```

Comment: What you mean when you say _"is inconsistent with the text file"_?

Comment: I mean the r.content is not completely printed.

Comment: I can confirm this is happening. Though this is so weird.

Comment: Yes, it's really weird. Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: I know this is not the solution but following works fine - from pprint import pprint
pprint(r.content)

Comment: I put your url value into the addr of my browser and it shows a page that has some graphics on it. Maybe you need to open f as binary: `f = open("test.txt","wb")`

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know the exact version of python you are using, I would venture to guess that it's not 3.x because of usage of print statements.

The problem is not with your print statement per se, **but**, *displaying* such long lines (this one is 175765 long) can frequently be a significant issue.  Python (particularly on windows), starts to become moody when dealing with lines that are several kB (176KB in this case) long.  Instead of trying to display the entire string in one statement, try to *break it up into multiple parts* and then display. You will see that there is no difference between whatever r.content is showing up on screen and what it's storing through f.write.

Just for your confirmation you can do this after your code:

```
fh = open("test.txt","r")
print fh.read()
fh.close()
```

You will notice that there will not be a difference between this and whatever is shown by the previous print statement.

I have tried this on python 3.4.x and linux, But the behaviour you mentioned is not observed with this combination of python and platform.

**EDIT 1**

This is what I have tried:

```
import requests
url = "http://www.aastocks.com/tc/stocks/analysis/company-fundamental/financial-ratios?symbol=0001&period=4"
r = requests.get(url)
a = print(str(r.content))
f = open("test.txt","w")
f.write(str(r.content))
f.close()
f = open("test.txt","r")
print(f.read())
f.close()
```

and here is the output:
http://pastebin.com/R0j0mYe5

**EDIT 2**

I didn't notice the header was getting cut. I tried it in 2.x and saw the behavior. **That does seem to be a problem**. Apparently there are some issues popping up when scanning through the html and decoding ot for print. :

This is what I saw:

```
print r.content[0:500]
print "*****"
print r.content[0:1000]
```

Gives and op like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"> <head id="Head1"><meta name="keywords" content="公司資料, 主要財經比率, 流動比率, 股東權益回報率, 總資產回報率, 邊際利潤率, 派息比率" /><meta name="description" content="公司資料, 財務比率, 變現能力, 償債能力

*****

</script> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> <link rel="stylesheet" type="teonal.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"> <head id="Head1"><meta name="keywords" content="公司資料, 主要財經比率, 流動比率, 股東權益回報率, 總資產回報率, 邊際利潤率, 派息比率" /><meta name="description" content="公司資料, 財務比率, 變現能力, 償債能力, 投資回報, 盈利能力, 營運能力, 投資收益, 綜合全年, 綜合中期" /><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" /> <script type="text/javascript">
```

As we can see when printing only the first 500 lines, the op is as expected, but there are errors when we try for more.

Something strange is going on when it tries to decode the entire doc.

However, in python 3.4.x I see this:

```
print(con[0:500]) #con = r.content
print(con[0:1000])
```

output:

```
b'<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"> <head id="Head1"><meta name="keywords" content="\xe5\x85\xac\xe5\x8f\xb8\xe8\xb3\x87\xe6\x96\x99, \xe4\xb8\xbb\xe8\xa6\x81\xe8\xb2\xa1\xe7\xb6\x93\xe6\xaf\x94\xe7\x8e\x87, \xe6\xb5\x81\xe5\x8b\x95\xe6\xaf\x94\xe7\x8e\x87, \xe8\x82\xa1\xe6\x9d\xb1\xe6\xac\x8a\xe7\x9b\x8a\xe5\x9b\x9e\xe5\xa0\xb1\xe7\x8e\x87, \xe7\xb8\xbd\xe8\xb3\x87\xe7\x94\xa2\xe5\x9b\x9e\xe5\xa0\xb1\xe7\x8e\x87, \xe9\x82\x8a\xe9\x9a\x9b\xe5\x88\xa9\xe6\xbd\xa4\xe7\x8e\x87, \xe6\xb4\xbe\xe6\x81\xaf\xe6\xaf\x94\xe7\x8e\x87" /><meta name="description" content="\xe5\x85\xac\xe5\x8f\xb8\xe8\xb3\x87\xe6\x96\x99, \xe8\xb2\xa1\xe5\x8b\x99\xe6\xaf\x94\xe7\x8e\x87, \xe8\xae\x8a\xe7\x8f\xbe\xe8\x83\xbd\xe5\x8a\x9b, \xe5\x84\x9f\xe5\x82\xb5\xe8\x83\xbd\xe5\x8a\x9b'

b'<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"> <head id="Head1"><meta name="keywords" content="\xe5\x85\xac\xe5\x8f\xb8\xe8\xb3\x87\xe6\x96\x99, \xe4\xb8\xbb\xe8\xa6\x81\xe8\xb2\xa1\xe7\xb6\x93\xe6\xaf\x94\xe7\x8e\x87, \xe6\xb5\x81\xe5\x8b\x95\xe6\xaf\x94\xe7\x8e\x87, \xe8\x82\xa1\xe6\x9d\xb1\xe6\xac\x8a\xe7\x9b\x8a\xe5\x9b\x9e\xe5\xa0\xb1\xe7\x8e\x87, \xe7\xb8\xbd\xe8\xb3\x87\xe7\x94\xa2\xe5\x9b\x9e\xe5\xa0\xb1\xe7\x8e\x87, \xe9\x82\x8a\xe9\x9a\x9b\xe5\x88\xa9\xe6\xbd\xa4\xe7\x8e\x87, \xe6\xb4\xbe\xe6\x81\xaf\xe6\xaf\x94\xe7\x8e\x87" /><meta name="description" content="\xe5\x85\xac\xe5\x8f\xb8\xe8\xb3\x87\xe6\x96\x99, \xe8\xb2\xa1\xe5\x8b\x99\xe6\xaf\x94\xe7\x8e\x87, \xe8\xae\x8a\xe7\x8f\xbe\xe8\x83\xbd\xe5\x8a\x9b, \xe5\x84\x9f\xe5\x82\xb5\xe8\x83\xbd\xe5\x8a\x9b, \xe6\x8a\x95\xe8\xb3\x87\xe5\x9b\x9e\xe5\xa0\xb1, \xe7\x9b\x88\xe5\x88\xa9\xe8\x83\xbd\xe5\x8a\x9b, \xe7\x87\x9f\xe9\x81\x8b\xe8\x83\xbd\xe5\x8a\x9b, \xe6\x8a\x95\xe8\xb3\x87\xe6\x94\xb6\xe7\x9b\x8a, \xe7\xb6\x9c\xe5\x90\x88\xe5\x85\xa8\xe5\xb9\xb4, \xe7\xb6\x9c\xe5\x90\x88\xe4\xb8\xad\xe6\x9c\x9f" /><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" /> <script type="text/javascript">\rvar _gaq = _gaq || [];\r_gaq.push([\'_setAccount\', \'UA-20790503-3\']);\r_gaq.push([\'_setDomainName\', \'www.aastocks.com\']);\r_gaq.push([\'_trackPageview\']);\r_gaq.push([\'_trackPageLoadTime\']);\rfunction OA_show(name) {\r} \r</script> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> <link rel="stylesheet" type="te'
```

But the output is similar in 3.x (like 2.x) if I try to decode the utf-8:

```
print(con[0:500].decode('utf-8'))
print(con[0:1000].decode('utf-8'))
```

Op:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"> <head id="Head1"><meta name="keywords" content="公司資料, 主要財經比率, 流動比率, 股東權益回報率, 總資產回報率, 邊際利潤率, 派息比率" /><meta name="description" content="公司資料, 財務比率, 變現能力, 償債能力

</script> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> <link rel="stylesheet" type="te
```

Comment: I am not assuming this to be a solution because - a) here you are printing the file contents, and there already being saved the correct contents, b) the initial part is being truncated while output is being printed to the content, c) I have seen x times bigger output than this being printed successfully. (PS, I didnt downvote your answer)

Comment: I tested both Python 2.7.9 and 3.4. This problem still occurs. But if I interpret the code in Windows cmd by "python xxx.py", the the content will print normally.

Answer (score 0):

There is an internal limit to how many lines the run console buffer can hold. It is limited to about 15K lines.

To increase this limit, you'll have to change the `idea.properties` file and add a key `idea.cycle.buffer.size` and adjust it accordingly.

See [this bug report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-9866) where the solution was detailed.

Comment: I have already adjusted the buffer size to 20000. But same issues.

Comment: Did you restart the IDE?

Comment: Yes. I try 2048, 20000, 999999 and restart Pycharm. It doesn't work for me.